# How to scroll to an image link on another page

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I need to scroll down to an image in another website that isn't our own when clicking on an href.

## What would be ideal

`<a href="https://example.org#https://example.org/image.png">foo</a>`

and the user who clicks on the link would automatically get scrolled down on the image on the page.

## Why it doesn't work

There isn't always an id for an image, nor can we scroll to a page based on image link.

We are currently not storing the `id` or the `class` of the parent div of the image.

## What we are thinking

One solution would be to create a service that searches for the image on the page and returns the closest div/id from the image

Another solution would be to create a web browser extension that would do this

Is ther any other way ?

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid as the image is on another website, you can't do much about it.Only you can try finding anchor on that website (if any) and use that link to scroll user to particular section.

Answer (score 1):

Use this: `<a href="https://target-website.com/directory#anchor">`. If that website doesn't have smooth scrolling for anchors, it will just immediately come to that part of the page